# Yii2 get 404 page from action whith several words

Tags: php, yii2

Action name in my controller is **actionMyEvents**. When I try `mysite.com/mycontroller/my-events` I get **404 not found**. Please help!

Comment: does Jeff Almeida answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 3):

This is not the normal behavior of Yii Framework. In the default configuration, you have to call yout action like this: 
`mysite.com?r=mycontroller/my-events`

To use clean URL like this, you have to configure your web server (probably Apache) rewrite engine, and do something like this in your config file:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    // Disable index.php
    'showScriptName' => false,
    // Disable r= routes
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'rules' => [
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ],
],
```